# Datatables.js project cell values into facets

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, datatables

Suppose I have a table listing products and categories the products belong to. One product can have one or many categories for example:

**products**

```
+----+----------+---------------+
| id | name     | category      |
+----+----------+---------------+
| 1  | 256GBSSD | Mobile,Mac,PC |
+----+----------+---------------+
| 2  | 8GBRAM   | Mac,PC        |
+----+----------+---------------+
```

I am creating facets to filter out products based on their categories. I am using [Datatables.js](http://datatables.net/index).
I would like to project the comma separated categories into individual facets such that a filter for Mac, lists both the products in the table above even though they have other categories.

How do I tell datatables.js that when it comes to the third column, it should list each category in the comma separated list as a searchable and unique (no duplicates) category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it to work out of the box with some tweaking.
Turns out that the [filter API](http://datatables.net/api) takes a few more arguments than I had originally seen.

`oTable.fnFilter(searchTerm, columnId, useRegularExpressions, useSmartFilter);`

If `useRegularExpressions` is set to false and `useSmartFilter` is true, then if a column *contains* the `searchTerm`, it is returned as a match.

What I had to do is just ensure the correct arguments were supplied when the searching the columns containing the CSV.
I admit I had to look into the API that @Ove provided(+1) to find out how to collect distinct items for the facets- but it was already implemented by the `fnGetColumnData` [plugin](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#functions) just needed a little tweaking.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this might solve it: https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf

Their example looks like just what you wanted: http://jsbin.com/esezof/1